# Android facebook SDK, show friend's wall in a webview?

Tags: android, facebook, sdk

How can i acces to a friend's wall with facebook SDK? I already have a list of friends where i can choose one, but i don't know how to redirect the user to it's friend's wall, do i have to use a request like "me/feed" or "me/friends"??
Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT:**
I just want to display the friend's wall on a webview, i already have an activity with a webview where i can see my wall using this URL:

```
http://m.facebook.com/?rdr#!/profile.php?_user=
```

using my logged user id in the _user variable.
I tried the same URL with the friend's id but I'm redirected to the current logged in user's wall.

Answer (score 0):

```
Using this url u can acess post on your friends wall feed.
```

https://graph.facebook.com/PROFILE_ID/feed?access_token=ACCESSTOKEN

Comment: profile_id = Id of ur friend whose wall u access. Profile ID is get using this url " https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=ACCESSTOKEN " using this url u can get your friend list which u are added in facebook.

Comment: access_token = access token is provided by facebook when u connect or login in with facebook username and password.

Comment: I tried using that url and i get what it seems to be a JSONArray displayed in my webview.

Comment: facebook provides only json data and using that data we get data and arrange and custom view apply in webview. data not displaying like facebook page.

Comment: @Deval Patel Can we show facebook user feed in our webview  same as like we open facebook in our phone browser. OR facebook sdk provide any dialog to show user feed?